# LLVM/Clang bug found in convenience method and NSClassFromString(...) alloc/release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, clang-static-analyzer

I am analyzing Objective-C iPhone project with LLVM/Clang static analyzer. I keep getting two reported bugs, but I am pretty sure that the code is correct.

1) Convenience method.

```
+ (UILabel *)simpleLabel
{
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 25)];
  label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
  [label autorelease]; // Object with +0 retain counts returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected.
  return label;
}
```

2) The [NSClassFromString(...) alloc] returns retainCount + 1. Am I right?

```
Class detailsViewControllerClass = 
    NSClassFromString(self.detailsViewControllerName);

UIViewController *detailsViewController = 
    [[detailsViewControllerClass alloc]
        performSelector:@selector(initWithAdditive:) withObject:additive];

[self.parentController.navigationController 
    pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
[detailsViewController release]; // Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object is not owned...
```

Are these some Clang issues or I am totally mistaken in these both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct in both cases.  For no. 2, you're probably confusing the analyzer by using `performSelector` instead of plain `initWithAdditive` (is there a particular reason you're using a selector?).  I'm not sure about no. 1, but maybe try initializing it with `[[[UILabel alloc] init...] autorelease]` instead of autoreleasing separately, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you. Case No. 2 solved, it seems that the analyzer really was confused by the previous code.
Should be:
UIViewController *detailsViewController = [[detailsViewControllerClass alloc] initWithAdditive:additive];
Case No. 1 still remains unresolved.

Comment: Case No. 1 is pretty mysterious.  That error message usually occurs when you misname methods (for example naming a method `newFoo` without returning a retained object).  I don't see anything that would cause it in your code.  It might be a bug in the analyzer.

Comment: Does the problem in case 1 go away if you tack autorelease on to the init or the return?  Anyway, you should report the bug to Apple - http://bugreporter.apple.com

Comment: I was just about to file a bug on this, but it seems it's fixed as of Xcode 3.2.5.